# Libpulsecommon-11.1.so: cannot open shared object file: installing qemu-virgil on ubuntu 18.04 for arm64

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, arm, shared-library

How to fix this ? (on ubuntu 18.04 for arm64 on jetson nano and I can't upgrade ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 because nvidia does not support 20.04 at the moment)

```
root@ziomario-desktop:# uname -a

Linux ziomario-desktop 4.9.140 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 8 00:07:34 CET 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux


root@ziomario-desktop:# sudo snap install qemu-virgil

error: snap "qemu-virgil" is not available on stable but is available to

install on the following channels:


edge snap install --edge qemu-virgil


Please be mindful pre-release channels may include features not

completely tested or implemented. Get more information with 'snap info

qemu-virgil'.


root@ziomario-desktop:# snap install --edge qemu-virgil

2021-02-14T13:09:37+01:00 INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart...

qemu-virgil (edge) 4.2.0 from Oliver Grawert (ogra) installed


root@ziomario-desktop:# sudo snap connect qemu-virgil:kvm

root@ziomario-desktop:# qemu-virgil

/snap/qemu-virgil/62/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-11.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

On ARM64 hardware you have to use special executable named:

```
qemu-virgil.arm64
```

Reference:

- https://github.com/ogra1/qemu-virgil-snap/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml#L25

Comment: done. problem is still there,intact as before.

Comment: I got the problem. Your hardware is ARM64, so it can't run `qemu-virgil` which is x86_64. You have to explicitly specify that you need `qemu-virgil.arm64` to run.

Comment: /snap/qemu-virgil/62/usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64: error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-11.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: What is the output of `arch` and `uname -a`?

Comment: aarch64 ; Linux ziomario-desktop 4.9.140 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 8 00:07:34 CET 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux